# Abstract class inherit another abstract class and implement an interface, all having the same method signature

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I tried the following and it works fine :

```
interface ICalculator 
{
    int CalculateSum(int x, int y);
    int CalculateProduct(int x, int y);
}

abstract class AbstractCalculator : ICalculator 
{
    public abstract int CalculateSum(int x, int y);
    public int CalculateProduct(int x, int y) 
    {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Bu when trying this it didn't work:

```
interface ISum
{
    int Sum ( int x, int y );
}

abstract class AbsSum1
{
    public abstract int Sum ( int x, int y );
}

abstract class AbsSum2 : AbsSum1, ISum
{
    public abstract int AbsSum1.Sum ( int x, int y );
    public abstract int ISum.Sum ( int x, int y );
    public abstract int Sum ( int x, int y);    
}
```

Can anyone help me ?
I'm just testing if it'is possible to do it in c#.I want a class to derive from AbsSum2 and implement all three methods.

Comment: Is it your intention to have three distinct implementations of Sum() method?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why are you trying to construct overly complex, difficult to read and use code? Be a good programmer: give each method a proper name that says what it does, rather than trying to trick the compiler into letting you have three methods with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the devil is in the detail, but to get your example to compile, your `AbsSum2` class just needs to `override` Sum (from `AbsSum`:

```
abstract class AbsSum2 : AbsSum1, ISum
{
    public override int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you implement an interface you pretty much have two options

1) Implement implicitly:

```
abstract class AbsSum2 : AbsSum1, ISum
{
  // Since the base class already has a **public** Sum() method with proper signature
  // ISum will use the method declared in the base class.
}
```

2) Do it explicitly:

```
abstract class AbsSum2 : AbsSum1, ISum
{
  // Manually redirect interface to Sum() method declared in the base class.

 int ISum.Sum(int x, int y)
 {
    return this.Sum(x, y);
 }
```

}